# Record added in nedb is single but why VUE store same record multiple times?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, vuex, electron-builder

I'm using electron with Vue. I'm saving data using nedb. I'm sending the event to background.js from vue component and when it returns with data it adds data in vuex in fibbonaccicaly.
like

- If I add 1 object let's say A then vuex store 1 object
- if I add 1 more object let's say B then vuex store has total 3
  objects (1 for A and 2 for B); and so on.

So I need to insert data in vuex only one time. How'd I do that ?

**// In CreateNewTodo.vue**

```
methods:{

// saveTodo method get triggers when user submit the form in modal

saveTodo() {
      if (this.isFormValid) {
        const newTodo = {
          task: this.task,
          priority: this.priority,
          eventDate: this.eventDate,
          createdDate: new Date(),
          completedDate: null,
          isCompleted: false,
        };

    // new Todo is an object that contains data that is requested from user 
    // from a form like task, priority and eventDate 

    ipcRenderer.send('createNewTodo', newTodo);
    ipcRenderer.on('createNewTodoResponse', (e, newDoc) => {
      if (typeof newDoc === 'object') {
        this.$store.dispatch('createNewTodo', newDoc);
        $('#createNewModal').modal('hide'); 
      } else {
        $('#createNewModal').modal('hide');
      }
    });
  }
},
}
```

**// In background.js**

```
ipcMain.on('createNewTodo', (e, args) => {

  // db.performTask is a function that insert document/record in nedb. 
  // I've used nedb-promises. In return we'll get promise.

  const dbpromise = db.performTask('todos', 'insert', args);

      // newDoc is the newly inserted document, including its _id

      dbpromise.then((newDoc) => {
        e.sender.send('createNewTodoResponse', newDoc);
      })
        .catch(() => {
          e.sender.send('createNewTodoResponse', 'error');
        });
    });
```

**// vuex store**

```
const state = {
  todos: [],
};

const getters = {
  getAllTodos(todosState) {
    return todosState.todos;
  },
};

const mutations = {
  CREATE_NEW_TODO(todosState, todo) {
    todosState.todos.push(todo);
  },
};

const actions = {
  createNewTodo({ commit }, todo) {
    commit('CREATE_NEW_TODO', todo);
  },
};
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to insert data in vuex store only one time per record. 
I mean If we insert data first time then it add one time in VUEX store. so total record will be 1
If we insert second record then data gets inserted 2 times. so total record will be 3
If we insert third record then data gets inserted 3 times then total record will be 6
But the above code is not doing this. I don't know where is the bug ?

Comment: But what is the code doing? and what is `data` in `createNewTodoResponse` is it an array or something else. if it is an array you have to make sure you push all elements not the array it self.

Comment: when we insert a record in DB in nedb we get the inserted record/document back as a response. data is that record/document that we are inserted.

Comment: @dreijntjens code updated. I'm just a newbie and excuse me for the bad naming convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you save a todo, you register a new listener for the IPC reply channel. The listeners all stay active and each picks and processes each event. That's not what you want, you want to process each response only once and electron has a method for that :) try this one:

```
    // register a listener to process the response (once)
    ipcRenderer.once('createNewTodoResponse', (e, newDoc) => {
      if (typeof newDoc === 'object') {
        this.$store.dispatch('createNewTodo', newDoc);
        $('#createNewModal').modal('hide'); 
      } else {
        $('#createNewModal').modal('hide');
      }
    });

    // send the request
    ipcRenderer.send('createNewTodo', newTodo);
```

Comment: That's not a silly mistake, not at all :) You could also keep the `ipcRender.on` method and just move it outside of the method. It's really easy to overlook.